# Gitlab CI job not triggered on tags

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci

I have a job on Gitlab CI that only triggers on tags:

```
deploy-prep:
  when: manual
  only:
    refs:
      - tags
      - /^v[0-9.]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/
```

When I create a tag via the web interface (Repository/Tags/New Tag), the job is triggered.

However, when I create the tag via Git command lines, the tag ends up in Gitlab but the job is not triggered.

For example:

```
git tag v0.0.1
git push --tags
```

How can I trigger my job for tags created via Git command lines? My use case is to be able to trigger the job from the tag created by the Maven release plugin.

Comment: Please check out these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698370/gitlab-trigger-pipeline-only-if-there-is-a-pushed-tag-for-all-branches-except-ma) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514416/trigger-gitlab-ci-pipeline-only-when-there-is-a-new-tag) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796018/how-to-run-a-gitlab-ci-yml-job-only-on-a-tagged-branch) , [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698370/gitlab-trigger-pipeline-only-if-there-is-a-pushed-tag-for-all-branches-except-ma) . Hope it helps!

Comment: And please try to use `only` in it's basic syntax (without using `refs`), maybe it makes difference.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried the only without the refs, but had the same result.

I don't know if that is the best thing to do, but I solved my problem by triggering the pipeline explicitly via Gitlab API after the release job: curl --request POST --form token=token --form ref=v1.0.0 https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/11779176/trigger/pipeline